# Why I get a length of 7 when I apply strlen() to a pointer to a single char?

Tags: c, char, strlen

The C code:

```
char c = 'a';
char *p = &c;
printf("%lu\n",strlen(p));
```

And I get a result 7 and I have no idea how this 7 come out.

Comment: Because `p`doesn't point to a valid (NUL terminated) string

Comment: @George Tried but still get 7

Comment: `strlen()` return type is `size_t`, you should use a different format: `printf("%lu\n",strlen(p));` -> `printf("%zu\n",strlen(p));`

Answer (score 2):

The variable `p` points to a single character, not to a null terminated string.  So when you call `strlen` on it, it attempts to access whatever memory is after `c`.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What's happening *in this particular case* is that after `a` in memory there are six non-zero bytes followed by one zero byte, so you get 7.  You can't however depend on this behavior.  For example, if you add more local variables before and after `a`, even unused ones, you'll probably get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that strings in C are really called *null-terminated byte strings*. All strings are terminated with a single `'\0'` character, meaning that a single-character string actually is *two* characters: The single character plus the terminator.

When you have the pointer pointing to `c` in your code, you don't have two characters, only the single characters contained in `c`. You don't know if there is a terminator after that character in memory, so when `strlen` looks for that terminator it will pass the character and go out into memory not belonging to any string to look for it, and you will have *undefined behavior*.

---

To try an illustrate what you have, take a look at this "graphical" representation:

```
+---+     +-----+----------------------
| p | --> | 'a' | indeterminate data...
+---+     +-----+----------------------
```

That's basically how it looks like in memory. The variable `p` points to the location where your character is stored, but after that in memory is just indeterminate data. This will be seemingly random, and you can not tell where there will be a byte corresponding to a string terminator character.

There's no way to say why `strlen` get the value `7` from, except that it finds six non-terminator bytes in the indeterminate data after your character. Next time you run it, or if you run it on a different system, you might get a completely different result.

Comment: Yes I know strlen will look for a terminator. My question is actually why the result is always 7 if strlen just looks for a '\0' in the memory.

Comment: @WeissZucker Updated my answer, hope it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Because strlen finds first null character starting from passed address. You pass address of only character, so strlen tries to look forward in memory until first null char in memory after variable c.

Anyway, you cannot be sure about result and it depends on compiler and all code you wrote. Moreover, you program can even fail with memory exception.